# Can anyone give an old version of Filezilla like as 3.2.0 download link?

Tags: server, ftp

I was using the latest version of filezilla on Ubuntu 15.04.
But it was unable to connect with the server.
In this case i need an older version of filezilla.
If anyone know about that then give me the source or the commands for downloading an older version.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an archive of filezilla, I hope you find the version which you are looking for! http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/files%2FOldFiles/

Comment: @FaysalHasan: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

[Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/files/FileZilla_Client/3.2.0/) has old filezilla file, so you probably can find 3.2.0 version there.